# Resource does not exist in current content-Xamarin Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

This error is really getting me frustrated and i have to be deleting my folders and adding them back before it is resolved. Can someone please save my life here? This is really making Xamarin boring for me here. I keep getting this error **"Resource does not exist in current content-Xamarin Android"** Along the line  in my project, it pops up and my build fails and i would have to be deleting files to resolve. Please help!

Comment: Please add a diagnostic build output to your question

Comment: I just fixed it ...Thank you